# How do you move PBIs from one sprint to another and reflect it to the Rolling up status

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We use the Rolling up Column to know exactly what is left for a feature. However, at the moment, if we re-estimate a PBI when moving to a new sprint, it will change the overall status and mess up the sprint velocity and sprint burndown chart for the closed sprint as well..
how should we handle PBIs that are re-estimated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an approach you can add a PBI to the backlog to bundle remaining work and feedback and re-estimate that new one at sprint planning.

Here are some links you can refer to, hope this helps:

- [Handling Work Left at the End of a Sprint](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/handling-work-left-at-the-end-of-a-sprint)
- [Undone Work in a Sprint](https://www.scrum.org/forum/scrum-forum/5305/undone-work-sprint)
- [How to handle stories that were not completed](https://www.scrum.org/forum/scrum-forum/25587/how-handle-stories-were-not-completed)

Comment: If we add a new PBI for the remaining work, is there a way we can automatically create the ticket based on the tasks that are left?

Comment: If you are referring to the remaining tasks as child items of PBI, I am afraid this cannot be automated, we can manually [create copy of work items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE3xK.png)

Comment: Right now, if I have backlog items that are not estimated with PBIs that are already done, my rollup progress shows as 100%

What can I do so that the rollup takes into account the ones that aren't estimated as well